# Unable to call method FirebaseApp.delete()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-indexing

I'm trying to remove the secondaryApp code as I wanted to prevent the function  `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` to automatically sign in after user creation

I've referenced the code below:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder fbo = new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
    fbo.setApiKey("YOUR_WEB_API_KEY");
    fbo.setDatabaseUrl("https://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/");
    fbo.setProjectId("YOUR_PROJECT_ID");
    fbo.setApplicationId("YOUR_APP_ID"); //Tested, App Id is required.
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = fbo.build();
    final FirebaseApp secondaryAuth = FirebaseApp.initializeApp([JAVA_CLASS_NAME].this, firebaseOptions, "secondary_db_auth");
```

And it works, however when I'm attempting to invoke the method

```
secondaryAuth.delete()
```

it returns an error stating the method cannot be invoked, just as the image below states.

[image: Error image]

I've checked the documentation from firebase [FirebaseApp.delete()][2] and expecting it to work however it is not. Everything else works out its just the `delete()` not working

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

The whole code implementation is as below:

```
private void CreateAccount() {
        String name = username.getText().toString();
        String phone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String email = emailAddress.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordTxt.getText().toString();
        String points = pointsTransfer.getText().toString();
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        FirebaseOptions.Builder fbo = new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
        fbo.setApiKey("YOUR_WEB_API_KEY");
        fbo.setDatabaseUrl("https://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/");
        fbo.setProjectId("YOUR_PROJECT_ID");
        fbo.setApplicationId("YOUR_APP_ID"); //Tested, App Id is required.
        FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = fbo.build();
        final FirebaseApp secondaryAuth = FirebaseApp.initializeApp([JAVA_CLASS_NAME].this, firebaseOptions, "secondary_db_auth");

        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(secondaryAuth);


        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your user name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your password again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!password.equals(confirmPassword)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password does not match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(points)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You need to send some points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(Float.parseFloat(currentUser.getPoints())<Float.parseFloat(points)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You do not have sufficient points.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            loadingBar.setTitle("Create Account");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, we are checking the credentials.");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();

            ValidateAccount(name, phone,email, password, confirmPassword,points, RootRef, firebaseAuth);
            secondaryAuth.delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be because of where you've placed the call. Can you show the function code where you wrote this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `FirebaseApp.delete()` as far as I can see in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp).

Once you've created a `FirebaseApp` instance, it will exist for the life time of that app. Given that `FirebaseApp` instances are quite lightweight, that shouldn't usually be a problem.

But they can of course be holding on to more expensive resources such as the service instances. If that is a concern for your app, be sure to isolate the usage of the names app instances and their services, so that they can be garbage collection once they're no longer needed.

---

It sounds like you want to detect if you're already initialized the `FirebaseApp`, which you can do by calling [`getApps()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#getApps(android.content.Context)), looping through the results and checking the [name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#getName()) of each. Alternatively you can call [`getInstance("secondary_db_auth")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)) and handle the exception it throws when the app instance doesn't exist yet.

Comment: So the function above works without implementing the `delete()`  for the first time. However when I'm trying to run the second time it throws an Exception Error. 
     **java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name secondary_db_auth already exists! **

Comment: I added some more information to my answer about that, based on reading the reference docs that I linked.

Comment: Yup, I've tried the above solution you've provided and it works.